# Prove $f(x,y) = |x-y|(x-y)$ is a function of class $C^1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Let 
>   $f(x,y) = |x-y|(x-y)$.
>   Say if $f(x,y)$ is of class $C^1$

So I have to prove 3 things: that it is continuous, differentiable and the derivative is continuous. 
 I wrongly thought it wasn't because the absolute value would give a sharp edge, in a similar way to what happens function $|x|$ in  single variable calculus. 
For the differentiability part , I tried finding the partial derivatives in a generic point of the form (t,t), since those are the points where the absolute value changes sign and I got 0, does this prove that the function is differentiable? ,if not could someone show how to prove it?
and how about the other 2 condition, continuity of the function an its derivative?

Answer (score 3):

The functions  $\phi(t):=|t|\,t$ with
$$\phi'(t)=2|t|$$
(check this for $t>0$, $t=0$, and $t<0$) and $d(x,y):=x-y$ are $C^1$ in their domains ${\mathbb R}$ and ${\mathbb R}^2$. Therefore $f=\phi\circ d$ is $C^1$ as well on ${\mathbb R}^2$.

Comment: Cool! I thought I had to use epsilon-delta definitions for all 3 conditions